# AWS SDK CreateChangeSet ValidationError StackName must be specified if ChangeSetName is not specified as an ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using Golang with AWS SDK Cloudformation to CreateChangeSet() and having trouble discerning the cause of this ValidationError:

```
error on CreateChangeSet: ValidationError:
StackName must be specified if ChangeSetName is not specified as an ARN.
        status code: 400
```

Anyone know how to get past this validation error when executing the changeset?

```golang
    changesetName := `some_unique_value_<timestamp>`
    stackARN := `arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:<accountID>:stack/sample-stack1/<GUID>`
    changesetName := instance.GetChangeSetName() // example:
    CreateChangeSetInput := &cloudformation.CreateChangeSetInput{
        StackName:     aws.String(stackARN),          // required field.
        ChangeSetName: aws.String(changesetName), // must be a unique value
        ChangeSetType: aws.String("UPDATE"),  // stack exists. using UPDATE
        TemplateBody:  aws.String(templateBody), // cfn template
        Parameters:    params}  // cfn paramaters

    // Issue AWS CreateChangeSet API call
    log.Println("Issuing AWS CreateChangeSet() API call")
    _, err = svc.CreateChangeSet(CreateChangeSetInput)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Got error on CreateChangeSet: %v", err.Error())
    }

    ExecuteChangeSetInput := &cloudformation.ExecuteChangeSetInput{
        ChangeSetName: aws.String(changesetName)}

    // Issue AWS CreateChangeSet API call
    log.Println("Issuing AWS CreateChangeSet() API call")
    _, err = svc.ExecuteChangeSet(ExecuteChangeSetInput)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Got error on CreateChangeSet: %v", err.Error())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just minutes after posting I realized the error was actually from the second api call. Providing the same StackName in the ExecuteChangeSet call resolved the validation error:

```
ExecuteChangeSetInput := &cloudformation.ExecuteChangeSetInput{
        ChangeSetName: aws.String(changesetName),
        StackName:     aws.String(stackARN)}
```